# Using the Selenium Webdriver, how can I find all classes associated with a div?

Tags: html, css, selenium

I have a div with multiple classes based on the permissions of the logged in user.

When logged in:

```
<div class="btn deleteButton canDelete">
```

When not logged in:

```
<div class="btn deleteButton">
```

I need a way to determine whether or not a div which has the `deleteButton` class also has the `canDelete` class.

I tried getting a list of all Elements with `deleteButton` and all Elements with `canDelete` and comparing them, but that doesn't work for two reasons:

1. It's inefficient to loop through two potentially large lists rather than one.
2. There are potentially other divs on the page with `canDelete`. This means that just comparing the two lists of Elements isn't effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".deleteButton.canDelete"));` ?

Answer (score 0):

One way to focus on the relevant area of a webpage is by creating containers and then looking for elements in these containers only. For example, you can identify and store your area of interest in a variable:

```
public static final String AREA_CONTAINER = "some_css_path";
```

then, once you have your area enclosed, you can look for your elements only within this area:

```
@FindBy(css = AREA_CONTAINER + "css_path") //here we are looking for specific elements within the area of interest
private WebElement element;
```

or in case of multiple similar elements:

```
@FindBy(css = AREA_CONTAINER + "css_path")
private List<WebElement> elements;
```

Answer (score -1):

This both ways must work for you:

```
By.cssSelector(".deleteButton .canDelete")
```

or

```
By.Xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'deleteButton') and contains(@class,'canDelete')]")
```